# Ожидание завершения сетевого запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, асинхронность

Всем привет !

Мне захотелось совместить Python и JS для попытки написания простого веб-чата.
Сервер на Python написать я сумел, и для клиентской части выбрал AJAX.
Почему нет websocket ?
Потому что пока что я не имею полного понимания его работы (как и AJAX'а собственно), а следовательно правильно сервер написать не смогу.

Функцию отправки сообщения из формы я написал, и приступил к функции получения сообщений для клиентской части.
Немного подумав я решил использовать следующий порядок получения сообщений.
Клиент делает AJAX-запрос и ожидает когда сервер ему ответит (timeout:0), сервер конечно же отвечает лишь по мере появления нового сообщения, и только после того как AJAX получит ответ и запишет его в html-код, он снова делает запрос. Таким образом и сервер особо не нагружается и лишнего сетевого трафика нет.

И тут-то вся проблема.

Я пробовал присваивать запросу переменную и проверять код элемента readyState, он должен быть равен 4 если запрос выполнился и ответ получен, но это замораживает страницу браузера.

В чем собственно вопрос.

Как заставить скрипт проверять получен ли ответ и лишь после этого делать запрос заново ?

UPD: добавил скрин того как в цикле проверку делал.

[image: Код функции]

[image: цикл]

Answer (score 0):

У jQuery есть метод $.when для того, чтобы дождаться разрешения нескольких ajax-запросов:

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
    /* здесь код, который должен выполниться по окончанию всех аякс-запросов */
});
```